# Geoserver sending empty vector tiles to Openlayers

Tags: openlayers, geoserver, vector-tiles

I have setup a geoserver with Postgres/PostGIS data store and enabled the geoserver vectortiles plugin. After loading up layers in the geoserver, the maps can be seen using the Openlayers interface provided by geoserver portal. Following this, I have been trying to get these tiles to render on front-end using a Openlayers, following the tutorial [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/vectortiles/tutorial.html).

The code works like charm for the sample world map data given with the tutorial but while trying to render any other map layer that I have in Postgres data store, it shows up blank.

My data in confined to a small region (country India) rather than the whole world and uses the projection system 'EPSG:4326'. The only changes made in the tutorial code is the layer name and projection_epsg_no.

The requests being made to geoserver return an empty response (no errors).
This is the request URL: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/layer_name@EPSG:4326@pbf/0/0/0.pbf

Comment: This would be better asked on gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In seeking the solution I arrived at this question. As I found (perhaps) the solution, I share it.
If you change the projection_epsg_no, you must enter a value of EPSG present in the tiling grids of your Geoserver. By default there are only the projections 4326 and 900913. The last is compatible with the EPSG 3857. If you enter another projection, you must, beforehand, create the corresponding tiling grid in your Geoserver.
Once done, do not forget to modify center: [0,0] to enter a value included in the range of your tiles. Otherwise, you will not have tiles displayed.
I hope this answer will be helpful